# Using gcc 3.4 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, gcc

By exactly following this [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/39629/135763), I was able to install gcc 3.4 on a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04. But, when I try  to compile a program, it fails with the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've looked at this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/401681/135763) and installed `build-essential` but that did not resolve the issue. I still get the same error.

Also, I installed the dependencies for g++-3.4 before installing it:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep g++-3.4
```

**UPDATE:**

Trying `gcc-3.4 -B/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu hello.c` removes the first two errors.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I read this [post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1750758) and tried it out on my system like below but it did not help:

```
gcc-3.4 -B /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/3.4.6/ hello.c
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

1. Run the following commands:

   ```
   LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LIBRARY_PATH
   export LIBRARY_PATH
   ```

This will eliminate the need to explicitly define the path whenever the C program is compiled.

2. Install the following packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
   sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
   ```
3. Create a symbolic link:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib64
   ```